# What is the point of null safety in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is the point of null safety to prevent the accidental assignment of `null` to a variable and then later doing something like `nullable_variable.foo()` which would cause a runtime error?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](https://dart.dev/null-safety):

> With null safety, your **runtime** null-dereference errors turn into **edit-time** analysis errors.

It means that a lingering problem that would otherwise become known only when its already too late will turn into an error that you get while you are developing, so you will know about it and can fix it before it ever reaches a customer.